# Counting with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Simple problem but I dont understand why the solution is the way it is:
You want to buy 6 bagels, and there are 3 types of bagels, plain sesame and everything. How many ways are different ways are there to select these 6 bagels.
THe answer would be C(8,2) but why cant isnt it 3^6. Since you have 3 ways to choose the first, 3 ways to choose the second all the way to  the last bagel. So 3 choices for each, and 6 of them so 3x3x3x3x3x3 = ?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer of $3^6$ would be correct if the bagels were numbered $1$ through $6$. But one everything bagel is the same as any other everything bagel, so this isn't the correct answer.

The correct answer $_8C_2$ can be shown with "stars and bars." Line up the six bagels (the "stars") and place the "bars" where you want to change flavors. If the first group is plain, the second group sesame, and the third group everything, then

$$| \star \star | \star \star \star \star$$

would be zero plain, two sesame, and four everything.

There are $8$ possible positions for either a star or a bar, and $2$ bars that you have to choose where to place them, hence $_8C_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Because the order of the bagels don't matter.
If the first three are plain and the last three are sesame, that's the same as if the first three were sesame and the last three were plain.

Onto why the answer is $\binom82$, this is a classical kind of problem tackled by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).
In this case, each different way corresponds to a different solution to

$$x_p+x_s+x_e=6,$$

where $x_p$ is the number of plain bagels, $x_s$ is the number of sesame bagels, and $x_e$ is the number of everything bagels.

Answer (score 0):

In your computation, you are choosing bagels in such a way that the order of the choices matters.  This would be an appropriate answer to the question

> Alice, Bob, Carol, David, Erin, and Frank all go out for bagels.  If there are three types of bagels, how many ways are there for the group to order bagels?

In this case, Alice can have any of three types, Bob can have any of three types, and so on.  The order in which the bagels are assigned matters (as this order tells use who got what bagel).

However, that is not the question that you are trying to answer, which simply asks how many different ways there are of grabbing six bagels from among three types.  If the bagels are plain ($P$), sesame ($S$), or everything ($E$), then the choices
$$ PPPESS
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
PSPSPE $$
are indistinguishable.  Thus we need a way of accounting for those permutations.

The classic approach is via a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument.  Order doesn't matter, so we can imagine putting the bagels in a specific order, say by flavor.  For example, place all of your plain bagels in a row, then draw a line.  Next, place all of your sesame bagels in the row, and draw another line.  Finally, put the everything bagels in the row.  You now have a row of bagels with two lines indicating the boundaries between flavors.

The only thing we really care about is where the lines end up, so we can visualize all of the bagels as stars, and imagine something like this:
$$ \ast\ \ast\ \ast\ \mid\ \ast\ \ast\ \mid\ \ast, $$
which would represent $PPPESS$.  More generally, we have 6 stars and 8 possible slots into which we can place bars:
$$ \_\ \ast\ \_\ \ast\ \_\ \ast\ \_\ \ast\ \_\ \ast\ \_\ \ast\ \_\ \ast\ \_.$$
We make a choice of bagels by **chosing** two of those eight slots, hence there are $$\text{"8 choose 2"} = {}_8C_2 = C(8,2) = \binom{8}{2}$$ ways of selecting six bagels.